# In Lua, how to print the console output into a file (piping) instead of using the standard output?

Tags: file-io, io, lua

I workin' with Torch7 and Lua programming languages. I need a command that **redirects the output of my console to a file**, instead of printing it into my shell.
For example, in Linux, when you type:

> $ ls > dir.txt

The system will print the output of the command "ls" to the file dir.txt, instead of printing it to the default output console.
I need a similar command for Lua. Does anyone know it?

**[EDIT]** An user suggests to me that this operation is called *piping*. So, the question should be: "How to make piping in Lua?"

**[EDIT2]** I would use this # command to do:

> $ torch 'my_program' # printed_output.txt

Comment: I believe this is usually called "piping" the output to file. Just mentioning this as it might help you find relevant results in web/SO searches.

Comment: can you give an example code showing how you would use this in Lua?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636812/read-console-output-realtime-in-lua?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here -> http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html

`io.write` seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Lua has no default function to create a file from the console output.
If your applications logs its output -which you're probably trying to do-, it will only be possible to do this by modifying the Lua C++ source code.

If your internal system has access to the output of the console, you could do something similar to this (and set it on a timer, so it runs every 25ms or so):

```
dumpoutput = function()
    local file = io.write([path to file dump here], "w+")
    for i, line in ipairs ([console output function]) do
        file:write("\n"..line);
    end
end
```

Note that the console output function *has to store the output of the console in a table*.
To clear the console at the end, just do `os.execute( "cls" )`.